# security vulnerability announced with the libyaml library used in the Psych gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am attempting to check whether my heroku app is infected and to ensure I am running on the patched version of ruby, by typing the following:

```
"heroku run “ruby -rpsych -e \”p Psych.libyaml_version.join(‘.’)\”” --app <my app>"
```

instead of returning the psych gem version number, I receive this error msg:

```
"-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'p Psych.libyaml_version.join(.)"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a `Gemfile.lock` and a repo on [GitHub](http://github.com/), you can use [Gem Canary](https://gemcanary.com/) to find problems. It's pretty good at finding and *explaining* issues.

Comment: Your code contains typographic quotes (`“`, `”`, `‘` and `’`) instead of straight quotes (`"` and `'`)  – is that just a copy & paste artefact?

Comment: Thank you first of all. I copied it straight of the GitBash command line.

Comment: Ill look into GemCanary. thanks.